# How many sequences length $n$, taken from $\{1,2,3,...,k\}$ that the sum of the $n$ elements in the sequence will be divisible by $k$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, permutations, combinations, multisets

I wonder if you can help me with this question I am being dealing with. My line of thinking was this:

I know that the sequence is of length $n$, so I divided it into $n$ cells. 
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+\dotsb +x_n=tk,\quad1\le t\le n.$$
So its like dividing $tk$ white balls into $n$ cells. But each cell has to hold at least $1$ white ball so the problem changes to divide $tk-n$ white balls into $n$ cells.

This is my answer but I don't know if I have counted options twice. On top of that I got an open answer (with operator sum) but I need a closed answer (without the sum). This is what I achieved so far. Hope anyone can help or give me a different way of thinking about this problem.

$$\sum_{t=1}^{n}{n+(tk-n)-1 \choose tk-n}=\sum_{t=1}^{n}{tk-1 \choose tk-n}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! You'll be much more likely to get a helpful answer to your question if you include any efforts you've made so far, or at least any ideas you've had about where to start.

Comment: 1) If you let k = 5 and n = 2, the sequences in question are 1, 4 and 2, 3. But your formula counts 13 sequences, so it definitely over counts. 2) In your first equation, t can never be n. 3) If you distribute tk-n balls into n cells, you can end up with more than k balls in a cell and with the same number of balls in different cells. I can't help thinking that you need a different approach.

Comment: @SteveB With $k=5$ and $n=2$ I would have thought the sequences in question would be $(1,4),\ (2,3),\ (3,2),\ (4,1),\ (5,5).$

Comment: If $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{n-1}$ are given arbitrarily, how many ways are there to choose $x_n\in\{1,\dots,k\}$ so that the resulting sum $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{n-1}+x_n$ is divisible by $k?$ In other words, given an integer $X,$ how many ways can you choose $x\in\{1,\dots,k\}$ so that $X+x$ is divisible by $k?$

Comment: @bof I was interpreting "sequence" to mean a subsequence of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, but I agree that nothing in the problem statement requires that. Allowing repeated use of the members of the set {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} moots my other observations, as well. So the formula over counts by less than I figured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok guys so i got the answer and i would like to know what do you think of it. so let's look at all of the sequences taken from $\{1,2,...,k\}$ that their length is $n-1$. there are 
$k^{n-1}$ such options. now if we look at any sequence as a sum of it's elements, we will see that the modulo $k$ of the sum can variate from $0$ to $k-1$. so there is only one way to add the last number in the sequence to make it a sequence from length $n$ that is divisible by $k$ . so the final answer is: $k^{n-1}$ ways

Comment: Yeah. That's it.